# change columns date column format in ruby sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, sqlite, format

I am using sqlite3 for my database environment. I have a column named date in ruby which I created using a scaffold like date:date so the type is date and it is also called date. The date is defaulted by ruby to display the date after typing in the _form_html.erb like e.g. "2015-01-18" .But I want it to display the date like 18-01-2015 on the index.html.erb view. SO no matter what I type into the form the format is set to the year first way so if i type 18-01-2015, then it displays it the other way round but if I type in anything random then it displays blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a file called `date_formats.rb` inside `config/initializers/`.

```
# config/initializers/date_formats.rb
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:date_month_year] = '%d-%m-%Y'
```

Now inside the view call

```
<%= date.to_s(:date_month_year) %>
```

The advantage of this approach is, you don't need to define your custome date format each and every view. Whenever you need this format, you just use the corresponding symbol of the format. Read [`#to_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) method.

Note: `Date#to_s` is an *alias* of `Date#to_formatted_s`.

Comment: i tried this and got NameError in Loggs#index, and    undefined local variable or method `date'

Comment: @mo2 Why are using `date`.. I gave it there as an example. Use your actual `Date` object.